# Why is the public_key of the CertificateSigningRequest no property?

Tags: python, cryptography

like the title explained, I don't know why the `public_key` of the `_CertificateSigningRequest` is no `property`? In comparison the `subject` is a property.

I use the cryptography module: [cryptography.x509.CertificateSigningRequest](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/reference/?highlight=certificatesigningrequest#cryptography.x509.CertificateSigningRequest)

Here the code snippet from the `_CertificateSigningRequest`:

```
def public_key(self):
    pkey = self._backend._lib.X509_REQ_get_pubkey(self._x509_req)
    self._backend.openssl_assert(pkey != self._backend._ffi.NULL)
    pkey = self._backend._ffi.gc(pkey, self._backend._lib.EVP_PKEY_free)
    return self._backend._evp_pkey_to_public_key(pkey)

@property
def subject(self):
    subject = self._backend._lib.X509_REQ_get_subject_name(self._x509_req)
    self._backend.openssl_assert(subject != self._backend._ffi.NULL)
    return _decode_x509_name(self._backend, subject)
```

Could anyone give me a hint, please? - Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does it matter?

Comment: @JamesKPolk I think for good code quality things should be implemented the same - if there is no reason for a difference. So do you know if there is any given reason?

Comment: You haven't even mentioned what module you're using.

Comment: @JamesKPolk thanks for the hint, I added the missing module name: cryptography.